# Create a copy of my website on Cpanel

Tags: cpanel

I want to link my mobile variant website version to the desktop version i.e "view website in desktop". You click this button and it will take you to the desktop version only. Program I use is Xara Web Designer. CPanel is where the files are hosted.

They have advised I need to create two copies of my website to do this.

I can duplicate my website but how would I go about uploading the two copies to CPanel? Also I would need to remove the robots.txt file from one of them because I do not want google crawling the duplicate site (SEO Issues).

Would I need two domains? I want to keep just one.

Thanks in advance please let me know if you need clarification on anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are better solutions with regards to SEO such as making your website 'mobile responsive'. But to answer your specific question, you are probably best to create a mobile website and set it up on a 'm.' subdomain (so you only need your 1 domain name). You can do this from cPanel under 'Subdomains'.

As for no-indexing the mobile website with robots.txt, the correct method is to use the 'canonical' tag. This is a good guide from Google on the subject: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/overview/select-config?hl=en